# Estimating $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{3x}} \ dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, estimation

I'm trying to solve this:

> Which of the following is the closest to the value of this integral?
>
> $$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt {1 + \frac{1}{3x}} \ dx$$
>
> (A) 1
>
> (B) 1.2
>
> (C) 1.6
>
> (D) 2
>
> (E) The integral doesn't converge.

I've found a lower bound by manually calculating $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3}} \ dx \approx 1.1547$. This eliminates option (A). I also see no reason why the integral shouldn't converge. However, to pick an option out of (B), (C) and (D) I need to find an upper bound too. Ideas? Please note that I'm not supposed to use a calculator to solve this.

From **GRE problem sets by UChicago**

Comment: The integrand tends to $\infty$ as $x\to0$, so the integral is improper, making (E) a possibility.

Comment: why there is no reason for the integral not to converge? limit of the function as x goes to 0 becomes infinity.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be iintegrand .$0$ is point of infinite discontinuity but $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) \sqrt(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt (3)}$ , a non-zero finite no. So integral does converge by comparision test

Comment: Actually we need a better lower bound to rule out B) (since the exact value is 1.59...)

Comment: (A) is out of the question, as $\sqrt{1 + 1 / (3 x)} > 1$ over $(0, 1)$.

Comment: What is the source of this question? why is it asking for an approximation by hand where approximation by Matlab, Mathematica etc are far more convinent and make sense? why values such as 1.2 , 1.6 ? and not something that needs to be evaluated like $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$ ?

Comment: @vonbrand, the inequality $\sqrt{1+1/(3x)}\gt1$ doesn't in itself rule out the possibility that the integral is less than $1.1$, which would give (A) as the answer.

Comment: @jimjim It's from the GRE problem sets by UChicago.

Comment: What are the details of the question? what book? what page? please show some proper information

Comment: @jimjim 1. I've quoted the entire question. 2. It's not from a book. 3. The material isn't publicly available at the moment. I just happen to have a copy of the problem sets from the authors. 4. You will need to define "proper information" for me to take any further action.

Comment: so are you saying it is not from https://math.uchicago.edu/~min/GRE/ ?

Comment: @jimjim Note the sentence "The following are links to our materials (*temporarily taken down* for UChicago REU stuff)." under the section titled **Our Materials**.

Comment: Proper information is the information needed to judge the difficulty or the guess the expected methods of solution that can be used. For example , if this was from a contest math then that is pertinent information. It being from a GRE exam, excludes usage of estimation methods that taught in university, and many of the answers are of no use in that context.

Comment: @jimjim Makes sense, that is a sensible definition. In any case, I think the question has been answered satisfactorily. I will add more information when I get time later.

Comment: Thank you, this is way too involved to be used for GRE, looks like authors are trying to gauge the difficulty of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+{1\over3x}}\,dx=2\int_0^1\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}\,dt$$

(from the subsitution $x=t^2$) as in Yves Daoust's answer, integration by parts gives

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}\,dt=t\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1{t^2\over\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}}\,dt={2\over\sqrt3}-\int_0^1{t^2+{1\over3}-{1\over3}\over\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}}\,dt$$

hence

$$2\int_0^1\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}\,dt={2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over3}\int_0^1{dt\over\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}}={2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over\sqrt3}\int_0^1{dt\over\sqrt{3t^2+1}}$$

Since $1\le\sqrt{3t^2+1}\le2$ for $0\le t\le1$, we have

$${1\over2}\le\int_0^1{dt\over\sqrt{3t^2+1}}\le1$$

Thus

$${2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over2\sqrt3}\le2\int_0^1\sqrt{t^2+{1\over3}}\,dt\le{2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over\sqrt3}$$

Now

$${2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over2\sqrt3}={5\sqrt3\over6}=\sqrt{75\over36}\gt\sqrt2\gt1.4$$

and

$${2\over\sqrt3}+{1\over\sqrt3}=\sqrt3\lt\sqrt{3.24}=1.8$$

Consquently

$$1.4\lt\int_0^1\sqrt{1+{1\over3x}}\,dx\lt1.8$$

and thus (C) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{3x}}dx=2\int_0^1\sqrt{t^2+\dfrac13}dt$$ proves convergence.

Then

$$\frac1{\sqrt 3}\le\sqrt{t^2+\frac13}\le t+\frac1{\sqrt3}$$
implies

$$\frac2{\sqrt 3}\approx 1.155\le I\le1+\frac2{\sqrt 3}\approx2.155$$

A tighter upper bound is obtained by noting that the function is convex and

$$\sqrt{t^2+\frac13}\le \frac1{\sqrt3}+t\left(\sqrt{\frac 43}-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right),$$ giving $$I\le\sqrt3\approx1.732$$
A tighter lower bound could be found by considering the tangents at both endpoints up to their intersection, but we can already conclude C.

[image]

The exact value is $$1.5936865\cdots$$ The bounds can be computed by hand, by squaring to avoid square roots.

Comment: I got this as well, but narrowing it down any further is difficult

Comment: What did you use to get $\sqrt{t^2+\frac13}\le \frac1{\sqrt3}+t\left(\sqrt{\frac 43}-\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$?

Comment: @S.D.: this is said in the answer.

Comment: @S.D.: convexity.

Comment: How did you get the first identity?

Comment: @vonbrand: this is a change of variable $x=t^2$.

Comment: Why the first line proves convergence?

Comment: @jimjim: the second integral is proper.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\sqrt{t^2+1/3}$ is a convex function on $[0,1]$, you may simply use the Hermite-Hadamard inequality to derive that

$$ \sqrt{2+\frac{1}{3}}\leq 2\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{t^2+1/3}\,dt \leq \sqrt{3} $$
so $(C)$ is the correct option.

Comment: Isn't f(0) infinity? I don't get it

Comment: @OvinusReal: we consider the integrand function *after* the substitution $x\mapsto t^2$, hence $f(t)=2\sqrt{t^2+1/3}$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that,

${\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{3x}+1}\,\mathrm{d}x$=$=\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+3}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Substitute $u=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+3}$ and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}x} = -\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+3}x^2}$,i.e $\mathrm{d}x=-2\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+3}x^2\,\mathrm{d}u$

${\displaystyle\int}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}+3}\,\mathrm{d}x$=$-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{2}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{u^2}{\left(u^2-3\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$
$={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{u^2-3}}}{\left(u^2-3\right)^2}+\dfrac{\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{3}}}{\left(u^2-3\right)^2}\right)\mathrm{d}u$

$={\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u^2-3}\,\mathrm{d}u+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-7}{3}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\left(u^2-3\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$

Perform partial fraction decomposition:

$={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\left(u-\sqrt{3}\right)}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}\left(u+\sqrt{3}\right)}\right)\mathrm{d}u$ + ${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{u+\sqrt{3}}\,\mathrm{d}u$

On solving this further we get

$\dfrac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3x}+1}}{3\left(\frac{1}{3x}+1\right)-3}+\dfrac{\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+3}+\sqrt{3}\right)}{6}-\dfrac{\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+3}-\sqrt{3}\right|\right)}{6}+C$

I.e,

$\dfrac{6\sqrt{\frac{1}{3x}+1}x+\ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+3}+\sqrt{3}\right)-\ln\left(\left|\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+3}-\sqrt{3}\right|\right)}{6}+C$

$\boldsymbol{\int\limits^{1}_{0}{f(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x =}$=${1\over6}[4 \sqrt(3) + \ln(7 + 4 \sqrt(3)]$

Approximation:
$1.593686504020857$,

i.e $1.6$.

The answer is option  $(C)$

Comment: Are you able to compute this without a calculator ?

Comment: no, I used a calculator to compute this @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Venkat Amith How do you define $ln (-1)$?

Comment: The question asked for no calculators. Why post answer that requires calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to use integration by parts to $I = \int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{3x}}dx$. First, transform integral into $\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\int\limits_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1 + 3x}}{2\sqrt{x}}$. Now $u = \sqrt{3x+1}$ and $dv = \frac{dx}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and what we get after IBP is $$\frac{2}{\sqrt3}\sqrt{x(3x+1)}|_0^1 - \sqrt{3}\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x}{3x+1}}dx = \frac{4}{\sqrt3} - \sqrt{3}\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x}{3x+1}}dx$$. We have $$\frac{5}{2\sqrt3} = \frac{4}{\sqrt3} - \sqrt{3}\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x}{3x + x}}dx < I <\frac{4}{\sqrt3} - \sqrt3\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{x}{3 + 1}}dx = \frac{4}{\sqrt3} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2} \frac{2}{3}x\sqrt{x}|_0^1 = \sqrt3$$
$\frac{5}{2\sqrt3} \approx 1.44$ and $\sqrt3 \approx 1.73$, so the answer is (C).

If one doesn't know the value of $\sqrt3$, we can check that $1.7^2 < 3 < 1.8^2$ and then $3 < 1.75^2$. Therefore, $\sqrt3 < 1.75$. From it we have $\frac{5}{2\sqrt3} > \frac{5}{2\cdot1.75} > 1.42$ and, for integral, $1.42 < I < 1.75$.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong with this solution?

Comment: See the comment of @jimjim: The question asked for no calculators. Why post answer that requires calculator?

Comment: Where do you need a calculator? Value of $\sqrt3$ is well-known, value of $\frac{5}{2\sqrt3}$ may be computed from it. But...okay, I'll make some more actions.

Comment: Just my was an opinion.  deleted your downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is an old post, I would like to show my attempt and people answers. However, there I was not trying to answer it as a timed test, but I was checking if that is a valid way of answering it. In fact, it is.

[See My Post Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4539591/evaluating-int-01-sqrt1-frac13x-text-dx-using-int-f-1x?noredirect=1&lq=1)

---

Here is a recent attempt, it may be useful for someone who sees the problem after a long time since posted.

If $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x$ converges, then it can be estimated by the following:

$$\large\boxed{\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\text{ d}x \approx \frac{b-a}{4}\bigg(f(a)+2f\bigg(\frac{a+b}{2}\bigg)+f(b)\bigg)}$$

---

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\text{ d}x$$

Put $x=t^2 \implies \text{d}x=2t\text{ d}t$. As $x$ ranges from $0$ to $1$, $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\text{ d}x \xrightarrow{x \rightarrow t^2} \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4t^2+\frac{4}{3}}\text{ d}t \space\space\space \text{[This proves convergence]}$$

Using the boxed formula above, we get:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{4t^2+\frac{4}{3}}\text{ d}t \approx \frac{1-0}{4}\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}+2\sqrt{\frac{7}{3}}+\sqrt{\frac{16}{3}}\bigg)$$

$$=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{3}}\bigg(2+2\sqrt{7}+4\bigg)=\frac{6+2\sqrt{7}}{4\sqrt{3}}=\frac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{3}}$$

But $\sqrt{7} \approx 2.6$ and $\sqrt{3} \approx 1.7$ implying that

$$\frac{3+\sqrt{7}}{2\sqrt{3}} \approx \frac{3+2.6}{2(1.7)}=\frac{5.6}{3.4}=\frac{28}{17} \approx 1.6$$