# Evaluating ${\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\text{ d}x}$ using $\int f^{-1}(x)dx=x f^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, limits-without-lhopital, gre-exam

While studying, I countered problem $\text{#}2$ [here](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week2.pdf). $\text{(UCHICAGO REU 2019 - MATH GRE PREP: WEEK 2)}$.

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3755288/estimating-int-01-sqrt-1-frac13x-dx) also. But wanted to know if my way is also correct (regardless of the time consuming).

---

$\color{red}{\text{Problem: Which of the following is closest to the value of this integral}}$

$$\color{red}{\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\text{ d}x?}$$

$\color{red}{\text{(A) }1 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{(B) }1.2 \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space \color{blue}{\boxed{{\text{(D) }1.6}}}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{(D) }2\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{(E) }\text{The integral doesn’t converge.} }$

---

***My Attempt:***

First, I found the inverse of $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}$ as a separate problem. As usual, I replaced $x$ with $y$ and $y$ with $x$, then I solved for $y$. I got $f(x)=\frac{1}{3(x^2-1)}$, which (using partial fractions), $f(x)=\frac{1}{6}\bigg(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\bigg)$.

Second, I evaluated $F(x)=\int f(x)\text{ d}x=\frac{1}{6}\int \big(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\big)\text{ d}x=\frac{1}{6}\log\bigg(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\bigg)$ [constant of integration is not added in this step, because we have definite integral, actually].

Next, I evaluated $F(f^{-1}(x))=\frac{1}{6}\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}+1}\bigg)$.

Finally, I used the formula:
$$\int f^{-1}(x)dx=x f^{-1}(x)-F(f^{-1}(x))+C$$

So, $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}\text{ d}x=x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}-\frac{1}{6}\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}+1}\bigg)\bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1}$

Plugging the upper limit of integration, $x=1$, we get $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{6}\log(7-4\sqrt{3})$

---

***My problems:***

- Even though this might not be an efficient way to save the time in GRE MATH SUBJECT TEST, I am still confused if my way was correct to solve such integral.
- If the way is correct, how can we evaluate it at the lower limit of integration, that is:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow {0^+}}\bigg(x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}-\frac{1}{6}\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}-1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}+1}\bigg)\bigg)$$

This should be $0$ as my calculator says. (By the way, calculators are prohibited in the test). I thought about applying L'Hospital's rule, but I did not success. I am not sure if this limit problem is harder than the original integral problem.

- How can we estimate $\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}-\frac{1}{6}\log(7-4\sqrt{3})$ to at least one decimal place? (No high accuracy is required as the given choices are far enough).

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Hm let's see. If we're only focused on approximating the integral, analytically solving it seems inefficient because in the end we do not seek such a thing, and as you can see, even if you have the closed form answer, it's useless if you cannot convert this into a decimal!

Instead let's use integral approximation methods. Our function decreases rapidly from infinity at $0$, before smoothing out to an asymptote. Hence, on the interval $(0,1]$, a good approximation method would be simpson's rule.

Since $0$ is a vertical asymptote, we'll use a left endpoint of $0.01$ for a close enough approximation. We'll use the 1/3 and 4-2-...-2-4 version of the rule.

Partition the interval into $4$ subintervals, to wit, $$[0.01, 0.25],\quad[0.25, 0.5],\quad[0.5, 0.75],\quad [0.75, 1]$$

First, establish $$f(x)=\sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}$$
We have $f(0.01)\approx 5.86$, $4f(0.25)\approx 6.11$, $2f(0.5)\approx 2.58$, $4f(0.75)\approx 4.81$, $f(1)\approx 1.15$.

Lastly, $\frac{\Delta x}3\approx 0.0833$.

In the end, our integral is approximately $$0.0833(5.86+6.11+2.58+4.81+1.15)\approx 1.7$$
This is closest to $\boxed{\text{D}}$.

Arguably, this margin of error is still pretty large. It would be up to you during the test to determine the number of subintervals/accuracy you want to compute this to. imo $4$ subintervals is a pretty good approximation, but if you want to be more sure you could to $6$ or $8$. Depends on how much time you have to spare i guess.

Comment: Did you read my post properly? (Regardless of the time consumption). Also, estimating the value of the antiderivative at $x=1$, and evaluating the limit as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I'm just providing a better way to solve the question you proposed. Your method is valid yea but would you rather spend 10 minutes calculating the closed form answer and then trying to wring a decimal out of your answer or spend 2 minutes getting a good approximation and moving on? Remember, you *don't* get calculators. If you want to stick with your way, I guess you could wait for someone else to answer. I *really* do not recommend your way though.

Answer (score 2):

I will concentrate only on the last two questions.

For the limit, you could simplify your expression. In the first term, move $x$ under the square root. For the expression in the log, multiply both numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{3x}$. Then you get $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(\sqrt{x^2+\frac x3}-\frac16\log\frac{\sqrt{3x+1}-\sqrt{3x}}{\sqrt{3x+1}+\sqrt{3x}}\right)$$
Then you just plug in $x=0$ and you get $$\sqrt 0-\frac16\log\frac 11=0$$

For the last question, you can easily calculate $\sqrt3\approx 1.73$. Just keep two digits after decimal point. Then $$\frac{2\sqrt 3}3\approx 1.15$$For the logarithm, it would be easier if you rewrite it using $-\log x=\log\frac1x$. Therefore your expression is $$1.15+\frac16\log(13.92)$$
The log is between $2$ and $3$, so your result will be between $1.15+0.33=1.48$ and $1.15+0.5=1.65$.

Comment: (+1) for this answer, help me more than Captain Chicky answer, because I am not taking it as a GRE problem (as I mentioned regardless of time consuming), but as a general integral problem where need to evaluate a limit and estimate an expression. Hope you can help me with the first problem if this is a really right way. Thanks!

Comment: The first part is right. And it's faster than the substitution followed by the partial fraction decomposition

Answer (score 0):

**A Hopefully Simpler Estimate**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{3x}}\sqrt{1+3x\Rule{0em}{.75em}{0em}}\ \mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{3x}}\left[1+x,1+\frac32x\right]_\#\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\left[\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac2{3\sqrt3},\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right]_\#\tag{1c}\\
&=\left[\frac89\sqrt3,\sqrt3\right]_\#\tag{1d}\\[3pt]
&=\left[1.52,1.74\right]_\#\vphantom{\frac89}\tag{1e}
\end{align}
$$
where $[a,b]_\#$ represents a number in $[a,b]$.

Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ $\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{3x}}=\frac1{\sqrt{3x}}\sqrt{1+3x\Rule{0em}{.75em}{0em}}$
$\text{(1b):}$ $1+x\le\sqrt{1+3x\Rule{0em}{.75em}{0em}}$ since $\sqrt{x}$ is concave on $[0,1]$
$\phantom{\text{(1b):}}\sqrt{1+3x\Rule{0em}{.75em}{0em}}\le1+\frac32x$ by Bernoulli's Inequality
$\text{(1c):}$ integrate each bound
$\text{(1d):}$ simplify each bound
$\text{(1e):}$ $1.52=\frac89\cdot1.71\le\frac89\sqrt3$ and $\sqrt3\le1.74$

---

**Comment on the Answer in the Question**

The computation in the question is correct. Here is essentially what is given in the question, but using integration by parts to simplify it a bit.
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\frac1{3x}}\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_{2/\sqrt3}^\infty u\,\mathrm{d}\frac1{3\!\left(u^2-1\right)}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt3}+\int_{2/\sqrt3}^\infty\frac1{3\!\left(u^2-1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac16\int_{2/\sqrt{3}}^\infty\left(\frac1{u-1}-\frac1{u+1}\right)\mathrm{d}u\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac16\log\left(\frac{2/\sqrt3+1}{2/\sqrt3-1}\right)\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac13\log\left(2+\sqrt3\right)\tag{2e}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ substitute $x=\frac1{3\left(u^2-1\right)}$
$\text{(2b):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(2c):}$ partial fractions
$\text{(2d):}$ integrate
$\text{(2e):}$ simplify

To evaluate the answer numerically, we can use $\frac87\le\frac2{\sqrt3}\le\frac76$ to approximate
$$
\frac2{\sqrt3}\approx\frac{15}{13}\tag3
$$
Since $\frac43-\frac{15^2}{13^2}=\frac1{507}$, we get that
$$
0\lt\frac2{\sqrt3}-\frac{15}{13}=\frac{\frac43-\frac{15^2}{13^2}}{\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac{15}{13}}\lt\frac{\frac1{507}}{\frac{15}{13}+\frac{15}{13}}=\frac1{1170}\tag4
$$
Thus, $\frac{15}{13}\approx\frac2{\sqrt3}$ to $3$ decimal places.

We can also use the series
$$
\log(u)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{2k+1}\left(\frac{u-1}{u+1}\right)^{2k+1}\tag5
$$
where for $u=2+\sqrt3$,
$$
\frac{u-1}{u+1}=\frac1{\sqrt3}\tag6
$$
Therefore, using the first $3$ terms to get $2$ decimal places
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(2+\sqrt3\right)
&=\frac2{\sqrt3}\left(\vphantom{\sum_{k=3}^\infty}\right.1+\frac19+\frac1{45}+\overbrace{\color{#090}{\sum_{k=3}^\infty}\color{#C00}{\frac1{2k+1}}\color{#090}{\frac1{3^k}}}^{\le\color{#C00}{\frac17}\color{#090}{\frac{1/27}{1-1/3}}=\frac1{126}}\left.\vphantom{\sum_{k=3}^\infty}\right)\tag{7a}\\
&\approx\frac{15}{13}\cdot\frac{17}{15}\tag{7b}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{17}{13}\tag{7c}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, to $2$ decimal places,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac2{\sqrt3}+\frac13\log\left(2+\sqrt3\right)
&\approx\frac{62}{39}\tag{8a}\\
&\approx1.59\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The question is: is my way correct?

Comment: Part of the question was also how to estimate the lower bound. I will check your approach for the upper bound.

Comment: I have verified that your method is correct, and given a method to approximate your answer to $2$ decimal places.